# What is the best way to invoke action in Form1 When Form2 is closed without using ShowDialogue in C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#

I've a project that contain 2 forms e.g. (Form1 , Form2 ).The user should be able to use any of the 2 forms while both of them are visible(i.e. Can use Form1 While Form2 is Open).At the same time when Form2 is closed there is an action that should be invoked in Form1 related to From2_close. I can't use Form2.ShowDialogue as it trap focus only to Form2 but user should be able to edit some data in Form1 while Form2 is loaded. Hope the question is clear, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I think you are trying to send a notification to a given set of forms based on any other forms actions.  This type of notification scenerio can be very easily handled by implementing the [**Observer Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Basically you have a single object that is the "observer" and it watches subscribers that register with it for messages.  When the observer receives a message from one of its subscribers (ie a form) it then notifies the other subscribers that it received a message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what i looked for

Answer (score 2):

Handle either the [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) or [VisibileChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) event.  When one of those events fires you know the form has been closed or hidden and can react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`ShowDialog` creates a modal dialog, which means that no other code in the calling thread will execute until the form closes. In this case, the dialog is blocking the GUI thread on your other form, which means that the user can't use it.

Instead of using `ShowDialog` to create an instance of Form1 from Form2 (or vice-versa), as I'm guessing you are currently doing it, just instantiate the other form.

**Form1's Load handler:**

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

***EDIT**

To allow each form to be closed without the other closing or the application exiting, do this:

In Program.cs, you'll see a call to `Application.Run` that creates a new instance of Form1 and starts the application. Replace that with the code from above, repeated twice, to create Form1 and Form2. After those two calls, add in a plain `Application.Run()` call.

Then, in each form, handle the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event by instead exiting the application if both forms are closed.

Comment: thanks, but in this case how could i invoke action in Form1 when Form2 is closed ?

Comment: @EgyEast: I misread your question, so ignore my edits unless they are useful to you

Comment: The solution is to have a 3 rd party object handle the message notification.  This is generally known as the observer pattern. See my answer above.